# Jumping Items On Category Page - CSS

Tags: css, magento2.3.1

We have upgraded and unfortunately many of the custom theme modifications do not work with the new system.  Most are easy fixes but i am struggling with this one which i suspect is probably an easy fix in the CSS somewhere

On hovering over the products, the products below are pushed down.  Can someone please suggest a fix for this issue?  Test site can be seen here;

https://magdev.challengept.com/gear/fitness-equipment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the perfect answer but will give you an idea for how to solve it.
Try adding this css class and see the difference:

```
.products-grid .product-item .product-item-info:hover {
    position: absolute;
    height: 430px;
}
```